# WCF service hanging on Proxy.InnerChannel

Tags: c#, wcf

I am maintaining an application that uses WPF services and I have never used a WCF service before so I'm struggling somewhat. Here is an extract of the code that is causing the issue:

```
        try
        {
            // Specify the Enquiry to be retrieved.
            getCharterDetails.charterEnquiryId = enquiryID;
            getCharterDetails.charterEnquiryIdSpecified = true;

            // Build the request object.
            request = new ACS.CBS.BusinessDelegates.CharterServices.getCharterDetailsRequest(getCharterDetails);

            // Instantiate and call the Service.
            CharterServices.charterServiceClient proxy = new CharterServices.charterServiceClient();

            using (OperationContextScope scope = this.CreateOperationContext(proxy.InnerChannel)) // <!---hangs here
            {
                using (proxy as IDisposable)
                {
                    response = proxy.getCharterDetails(getCharterDetails);                        
                }
            }

            // Extract the Charter Enquiry Object and return it.
            return response.@return;
        }
        catch (FaultException serviceFault)
        {
            Exception ex = handleServiceFault(serviceFault);
            throw ex;
        }
```

It hangs on the indicated line and I have no idea how to debug a WCF service. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Mark

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Pankaj, I can now step through that line the scope is created successfully. However, it now hangs on this line:

```
using (charterServiceClientProxy as IDisposable)
{
    _ratesOfExchange = proxy.getRateOfExchange(rateOfExchange); // <--- hangs here
}
```

Well, it actually hangs in Reference.cs (the auto generated service reference file).

Any ideas?

M

Answer (score 0):

Change offending line as follows:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
```